# How can I write Space between Characters with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I generated random numbers using `Math.random();`.
But they are separated by commas, like this:

```
5,7,8,10
```

How can I write a space between the numbers using JavaScript, like this:

```
5 7 8 10
```

**Here's my code:**

```js
let numbers = [
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
];
console.log(numbers);
let evenNumbersArray = [];
let evenNumbers = numbers.forEach(function (number) {
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(number);
    evenNumbersArray.push(number);
  }
});
evenNumbersArray.toString();
document.getElementById(
  "showEvenNumbers"
).innerText = `Our evenNumbers are :  ${evenNumbersArray}`;
```

Comment: use `array.join(' ')` instead of `toString()`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To remove ',' and replace them with space character, you should use replaceAll method on the string.
In another words, You convert your array to string with `.toString()` method, then use `.replaceAll('a', 'b')` to replace a with b in whole string.

More info about replace and replaceAll method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

```js
const numbers = [
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
  Math.round(Math.random() * 100 - 1 + 1),
];

const evenNumbersArray = [];
numbers.forEach(function (number) {
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    evenNumbersArray.push(number);
  }
});

const text = evenNumbersArray.toString().replaceAll(',',' ');

// then add text to DOM:
document.getElementById("showEvenNumbers").innerText = `Our evenNumbers are :  ${text}`;
```

```html
<p id="showEvenNumbers"></p>
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `array.join(' ')`

Comment: You should not do it like this. While it solves the problem, it does it in a wasteful manner. Just use join instead of toString (which internally is just a join). Now you add another 'slow' operation extra (the replace) which isnt needed to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better way to do this :

```js
// Specify the length of the array
const length = 10;

// Specify the minimum and maximum values
const min = 1;
const max = 100;

// Generate a random number between min and max (inclusive)
const randomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;


// Create an array filled with random numbers
const numbers = Array.from({ length }, randomNumber);

// Print the array contents separated by whitespace
console.log(numbers.join(' '));
document.write(numbers.join(' '));
```